# About topological conjugacy

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory, stability-theory

The Smale horseshoe map $f$ is desribed in this page: [What's the point of a Horseshoe map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357034/whats-the-point-of-a-horseshoe-map)

A striking feature of this system is the stability of its dynamics: given any diffeomorphism $g$ sufficiently $C¹$-close to $f$, then there exist a homoemorphism $h$ such that $f∘h=h∘g$. This is the topological conjugacy.

My **question** is: Why the map $g$ should be of class $C¹$. Why this definition does not works with for example $C⁰$ or a discontinuous map $g$ considered as a small variation of the map $f$.

Comment: Because $C^0$ perturbations are too damaging. They can destroy the original structure of the system.

Comment: @SimingTu: Can you elaborate with this by giving some explanations with some references.

Comment: For example, consider a system with a hyperbolic fixed point, you can make a $C^0$ perturbation to make that in a small neighborhood of the fixed point, all points are fixed point.